# Add record on button click only

Tags: ms-access-2010

I have a form that has the 'data entry' property set to yes. It is bound to a table. When I start filling in the form it automatically saves it. I do not want this to happen. I only want the form to save to the table when I press a button. Any easy way to do this? w/o vba. If i can only do this with vba let me know how to do it that what.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best way to do this is with an unbound form. When the user clicks save, you can run a query to update your table from the controls.

**Using a recordset**

```
 Dim rs As Recordset
 Set rs=CurrentDB.Openrecordset("MyTable")

 rs.AddNew
 rs!Field1 = Me.Field1
 rs.Update
```

If you wanted to update a record where you already knew the primary key, you could say:

```
 Dim rs As Recordset
 Set rs=CurrentDB.Openrecordset("SELECT * FROM MyTable WHERE ID=" & Me.txtID)

 rs.Edit
 rs!Field1 = Me.Field1
 rs.Update
```

**Using a query that you have created in the query design window**

SQL for the query

```
 INSERT INTO MyTable (Field1) 
 VALUES ( Forms!MyForm!Field1 )
```

VBA

This will give a warning

```
 DoCmd.OpenQuery "MyQuery"
```

This will not

```
 CurrentDb.Execute "Query2", dbFailOnError
```

You could also use dynamic SQL or a query with parameters that you assign in code.

Comment: I've researched this and when i press a button to run a query it just opens up the query window. Thats it. Dont know what am i doing wrong.

Comment: It took awhile but i got it. TY