# on Button press If(No record exist) Then create Else Update

Tags: forms, vba, ms-access-2010

I have an unbound form. On the form i have a save button. As of now when you press the save button it saves the information on the form to a record, but every time you press save it adds a new record instead of updating it. I need it to Update the current record instead of adding a new record. Any ideas is appreciated.

here is my code:

```
Dim dblocal As DAO.Database
Dim rst As DAO.Recordset

Set dblocal = CurrentDb()
Set rst = dblocal.OpenRecordset("SUBJECT_DATABASE", dbOpenDynaset)

'Prim. ID var.
Dim EvtIDkey As Long

With rst
.AddNew
.Fields("LAST NAME") = Me.LNameTxtB
.Fields("FIRST NAME") = Me.FNameTxtB
.Fields("GENDER") = Me.GenderCboB
.Fields("DOB") = Me.DOBTxtB


'inserts primary id into textB
Me.EvtIDKeyTxtB = .Fields("ID")

.Update
End With

End If
```

I was thinking to add a if statement with the following conditions:
If EvtIDKeyTxTB is not empty update exist record. However, how do i update an existing record?

If i have the Primary key would i be able to get and update the record that way?

Comment: You shou add a note to your original, question rather thn asking new questions http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12205769/add-record-on-button-click-only