# How to use 'GoToRecord' Command to get a record by Primary Key- VBA Acess 2010

Tags: forms, vba, ms-access

How to use 'GoToRecord' Command to get a record by Primary Key?

Comment: Your question is a little vague, are you trying to retrieve the Primary key ID, or navigate to a record given the ID?

Comment: Victor, I have updated your original question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12205769/add-record-on-button-click-only

Comment: No, it is not vague. Whoever ran into this typical Microsoft mess knows what this is about: the function CurrentRecord returns an ID (PrimaryKey), but for the GoToRecord function it expects absolute number of the row. If records have been deleted, the absolute record number no longer matches the ID.

Comment: I voted for reopen as almost every access programmer run into this problem and knows exactly what the OP means (at least after the question has been updated).

Answer (score 16):

I suspect you wish to move to a record given the primary key.

```
MyKey = 3
With Me.Recordset
    .FindFirst "ID=" & MyKey

    If .NoMatch Then
        MsgBox "Not found"
    End If
End With
```