# Form field reverts to last record when I requery

Tags: vba, ms-access

I have an Access Form to enter a new record.
I have a date field that requerys the form when you update it, to update another text box.
Each time this happens, the Form reverts to the record you were in before adding a new record.

I googled and came up with [this solution](https://www.baldyweb.com/Requery.htm):

```vb
Rem https://www.baldyweb.com/Requery.htm
Dim lngPK As Long 'change data type if yours is different

'set variable to current record ID
lngPK = Me.EmpID

Me.Requery
'return form to original record
With Me.RecordsetClone
    .FindFirst "EmpID = " & lngPK
    'if your key field is text use this line instead
    '.FindFirst "EmpID = " & Chr(34) & lngPK & Chr(34)
    If .NoMatch Then 'just in case another user deleted it in the interim
        MsgBox "Record not found!", vbCritical
    Else 'go to that record
        Me.Bookmark = .Bookmark
    End If
End With
```

I have it in the date field box `After_Update` property and changed references as required to work with my application.

It all seems to work, but each time it triggers this part of the code: `MsgBox "Record not found!", vbCritical` and reverts to the previous record.

I have added in my own message boxes at various points that confirm that it is recording the correct record ID number, but then says it can't find it.

After the process if I come out the record and back in, the new record is there, as it should be.

I have changed this line to read: `.FindFirst "[Orders].[Ack_Number] = " & lngPK`

I think this is what I need to reference my field. I tried adding or removing various square brackets.
To record the ID number in the first place I used: `lngPK = Me.[Orders.Ack_Number]`. This records the correct number as confirmed by my msgbox.
I tried removing the 2 square brackets in the 2nd reference, but this doesn't change anything.

Comment: Assuming that the added record is always the last record you could use `DoCmd.GoToRecord ,,,acLast`

Comment: I can't see how the original code worked since it is using a recordset clone.  Bob's docmd approach works great in most cases but for more control the same basic code works in the original recordset see the first answer to this closed question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12256635/how-to-use-gotorecord-command-to-get-a-record-by-primary-key-vba-acess-2010

Answer (score 0):

So your problem is that when adding a new record, after executing the Requery method for the Form, you will not be able to return to the newly added record, but will run to the last record before adding, right?

If the answer is YES, then try this first:

Add this code or apply these object methods and logic to your **date field** control's **AfterUpdate** event.

```vb
Private Sub your_date_field_AfterUpdate()
    If Me.NewRecord Then
        Me.Refresh 'before requery Me, save the new record first
        Me.Requery
        Me.Recordset.MoveLast 'use this to go to the newly added record
    End If
End Sub
```

In the case of the example code you found, it just doesn't take into account the fact that new records are being added. (His default context and occasion does not include when adding records) So just add the judgment on adding new records `If Me.NewRecord Then Me.Refresh` or `If Me.NewRecord Then DoCmd.RunCommand acCmdSaveRecord`：

```vb
Sub Access_Form_reverts_to_last_record_when_I_requery()
    Dim lngPK As Long 'change data type if yours is different
    
    'set variable to current record ID
    lngPK = Me.EmpID
       
    Rem when adding a record, this has to be before running Requery.
    If Me.NewRecord Then Me.Refresh
    '    or
    'If Me.NewRecord Then DoCmd.RunCommand acCmdSaveRecord
    
    Me.Requery
    'return Form to original record
    With Me.RecordsetClone
        .FindFirst "EmpID = " & lngPK
        'if your key field is text use this line instead
        '.FindFirst "EmpID = " & Chr(34) & lngPK & Chr(34)
        If .NoMatch Then 'just in case another user deleted it in the interim
            MsgBox "Record not found!", vbCritical
        Else 'go to that record
          Me.Bookmark = .Bookmark
        End If
    End With
End Sub
```